# Geany IDE: "no module named matplotlib"

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I downloaded anaconda onto my Linux ubuntu system and am trying to plot data points from a text file. When I hit execute, the terminal tells me that there is no matplotlib recognized even though it is included in anaconda.

I've made sure that matplotlib is installed and up to date. My system tells me that it is installed, but Geany (my IDE) won't recognize that it is installed

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv
x = []
y = []

with open('data.v3.txt') as datafile:
    plots = csv.reader(datafile, delimiter=',')
    for row in plots:
        x.append(int(row[0]))
        y.append(int(row[1]))

plt.plot(x,y, label='Loaded from file!')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.title('Data')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

I should get a plot to appear in my terminal, but I always get the error message: "no module named 'matplotlib'"

Comment: how do I check that? I'm using Geany so should I change the compiler and executor to anaconda from the "set build commands?"

Comment: In Geany in menu `Build` you can define own tools and there you can define path to Python used by Geany.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the run command in Geany with python3 "%f" instead of python "%f".